# protractor promise fn is not a function

Tags: javascript, selenium-webdriver, promise, protractor

**EDIT:** I think i understand why it is not working. I cant pass Arguments along when calling flow.execute(getSpendermeldung). Someone has an better  than wrapping the ApiCall in another function and using "global" variables? I intend to have this in another file and use require when necessary.

**Original Post:**
For my protractor tests i want to get test data out of a database. I did this with the nodejs http module, which so far is working. Since i test with this data i have run in synchronization issues. I got around them with jasmines callback solution. However i find this to be to inflexible and would like to use promises and the control flow. Sadly when ever i execute my code i get an Error: fn is not a function. Somewhere deep in the webdriver/lib/promise.js

This is my function:

```
function getSpendermeldung(kennnummer) {
var http = require('http');

var defer = protractor.promise.defer();

var options = {
    host: 'localhost',
    path: '/blabla/' + kennnummer
};

var callback = function (response) {
    var body = '';
    response.on('data',
        function (chunk) {
            body += chunk;
        });
    response.on('end',
        function () {
            spendermeldung = JSON.parse(body);
            defer.fulfill('json parsed');
        });
};

http.get(options, callback).end();

return defer.promise;
}
```

I call it with this:

```
 var flow = browser.controlFlow();
 flow.execute(getSpendermeldung('D0000001'));
```

Someone has an idea what i am missing. Thanks.

PS: Would love to post the stacktrace, but i dont get the formatting right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are calling the function - `getSpendermeldung` rather than passing it as an argument. And yes, I think you can achieve it without using global variables and using a require from an another file

More details on the arguments that `flow.execute` are [here](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/javascript/module/selenium-webdriver/lib/promise_exports_ControlFlow.html)

```
var apiCall = require('the-file-that-containsthe-function')
var flow = browser.controlFlow();
flow.execute(function(){return getSpendermeldung('D0000001')});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to return the deferred object `defer` and *not* `defer.promise`.

Secondly, A minor correction, you are fulfilling the promise before ending the request. Shouldn't you instead do this?

```
http.get(options, callback).end(function nowFulfillPromise() {
   defer.fulfill('json parsed');
});
```

Comment: I gave both a try and always ended in an infinite loop. I assume this is because get() is calling end() implicit, as opposed to request(). However returning the defer seems to be wrong.

Comment: In my projects I return defer all the time.